# Amazon RDS Snapshot system is the same Automated backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am in doubt if the Amazon RDS Snapshot system has retention and if it is the same as automated backup?

Comment: Does https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html not answer all the questions?

Comment: I read this documentation, https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/faqs/#23  but I didn't find it. I only found retention of automated backup, but I don't know if the Snapshot System is the same as the automated backup

Comment: In case you are wondering why this is downvoted, it is probably because it does not show any indication of research before posting question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Welcome to SO and I hope this doesn't discourage you from using Stackoverflow in future.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Amazon RDS Snapshot, it is retained forever (until you delete it). This snapshot can be triggered through the management console, AWS CLI or programmatically via an AWS SDK.

Amazon RDS can also perform automated snapshots, which are retained for the period of time configured when the RDS instance was launched (up to 35 days).